# How to check the word in an array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a default array for example

```
a=["and","a","in","&"] etc...
```

Iam getting a dynamic text, which iam converting it into an array. for example.

```
b=["harry","in","connect"]
```

I need to highlight by avoiding "in" the array.

So harry and connect will be highlight but not the in?

How to compare or check the array in jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `$.inArray` or `$.grep`, i.e.

```
var a=["and","a","in","&"];
var b=["harry","in","connect"];

var c = $.grep(b, function(n){
    return $.inArray(n,a) == -1;
});
```

This will return a new array, containing only the words NOT present in array `a`

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kaFvw/

If you need it to return an array with all the words PRESENT in array `a`, just change the `==` operator to `!=`

Comment: this probably makes most sense, considering that I didn't really understand the original question.

Comment: @Thor I am getting an empty array, but the new array are not coming up. what to do?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem? Is `a` or `b` empty, or is `c` empty after you've run `a` and `b` through it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery.each.

```
     jQuery.each(b, function() {
           // 'this' will hold value . you can do your operation here
          if(this!="in")
         {
            //heighlight
         }
       });
```

You can find more details [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.each(b, function(c,d) {
       if (d == "in") //do not highlight
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

do something like this;

```
a=["and","a","in","&"]
b=["harry","in","connect"]
var foo;
$.each(b, function() { 
  if(Query.inArray(this, a)!=-1)
  {
     foo += "<strong>" + this + "</strong>";
  }
  else{
     foo += this;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to highlight all the elements in the second array that are not contained by the first one. If that's the case, then something like this should work :

```
for(var i=0,l=b.length;i<l;i++)
    {
        if(a.indexOf(b[i]) == -1)
            {
                // highlight b[i]
            }
        else
            {
                // do no highlight b[i]
            }
    }
```